# Dynamically retrieve fields across multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design

So I have a design where people are put into groups and those groups determine what properties are saved with each person.

So if later I decide I want to have VIP customers and record their VIP numbers I can just create a new group called "VIP Members" with a property "VIP_Number" and place those customers in that group.

Therefore Employees and other Customers do not have that field which would be irrelevant to them.

**Now what is the best way to fetch all the required data from the separate tables for a given person? I need a solution that supports the data tables being added to at a later date.**

Here is the table design.

Notes:

- The 'd' prefix is for a data table
- The 'x' prefix is for a cross reference table
- The 'p' prefix is for a property
- I have used different length IDs to help with readability
- John Smith is an Employee and therefore a Person also.
- Anna Backhouse is a Customer and therefore a Person also.
- Mr Both is both an Employee and a Customer and therefore a Person also.

**dPeople**

```
ID                   pFirst_Name          pLast_Name
----------------------------------------------------------
001                  John                 Smith
002                  Anna                 Backhouse
003                  Mr                   Both
```

**dEmployees**

```
ID                   pBadge_Code
----------------------------------------------------------
01                   MB2012
02                   JS2012
```

**dCustomers**

```
ID                   pPhone_Number
----------------------------------------------------------
01                   1800 backhouse
02                   1800 both
```

**dGROUPS**

```
ID                   pGroup_Name
----------------------------------------------------------
1                    People
2                    Employees
3                    Customers
```

**xGROUPS**

```
dGROUPS_ID_parent    dGROUPS_ID_child
----------------------------------------------------------
1                    1
1                    2
1                    3
```

**xPeople**

```
dPeople_ID           dGROUPS_ID
----------------------------------------------------------
001                  2
002                  3
003                  2
003                  3
```

**xEmployees**

```
dPeople_ID           dEmployees_ID
----------------------------------------------------------
001                  02
003                  01
```

**xCustomers**

```
dPeople_ID           dCustomers_ID
----------------------------------------------------------
002                  01
003                  02
```

Desired result if looking up Mr Both:

```
ID    pFirst_Name  pLast_Name  pBadge_Code  pPhone_Number
----------------------------------------------------------
003   Mr           Both        MB2012       1800 both
```

Desired result if looking up John Smith:

```
ID    pFirst_Name  pLast_Name  pBadge_Code  
----------------------------------------------------------
001   John         Smith       JS2012
```

Desired result if looking up Anna Backhouse:

```
ID    pFirst_Name  pLast_Name  pPhone_Number
----------------------------------------------------------
002   Anna         Backhouse   1800 backhouse
```

I can get a list of all the groups they are in using:

```
SELECT `dGROUPS`.`ID` AS `Group ID`, `dGROUPS`.`pGroup_Name` AS `Group Name` FROM `dGROUPS`, `xGROUPS` WHERE `xGROUPS`.`dGROUPS_ID_parent` = `dGROUPS`.`ID` AND (`xGROUPS`.`dGROUPS_ID_child` IN (SELECT `dGROUPS_ID` FROM `xPeople` WHERE dPeople_ID = 003))
```

This is helpful when I have further sub groups such as People > Employees > Managers

I am thinking I would need to run this query and use it to form another query dynamically to get the desired results. I do not mind using two queries however one would be preferred.

Perhaps there is a solution using views?

I am using PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the select clause, the asterisk select all columns, even the new columns added later to the tables.

Mr Both:

```
  --select dp.ID, dp.pFirst_Name, dp.pLast_Name, de.pBadge_Code, dc.pPhone_Number
    select dp.*, dp.*, dp.*, de.*, dc.*
    from dPeople dp join xCustomers xc
      on dp.id = xc.dPeople_ID
    join dCustomers dc
      on xc.dCustomers_ID = dc.ID
    join xEmployees xe
      on dp.id = xe.dPeople_ID
    join dEmployees de
      on  xe.dEmployees_ID = de.ID
```

Comment: This does not work if new properties are added to tables at a later date or if a person is added to another group. I need a dynamic solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind about having empty columns (you could handle them in the php side) you can get the desired result without using dynamic queries. This would also allow you to throw away grouping tables: dGROUPS and xGROUPS don't give any added value **for just this purpose** the relation among entities is already given by the actual data, they only generate [Update anomalies](https://www.google.com/search?q=Update%20anomalies&ie=utf-8).

This a sample made with postgres (but you can do the same with mysql).

```
postgres=# with dPeople(ID, pFirst_Name, pLast_Name) as (
postgres(#              values('001','John','Smith')
postgres(#              union all
postgres(#              values('002','Anna','Backhouse')
postgres(#              union all
postgres(#              values('003','Mr','Both')
postgres(#      ), dEmployees(ID, pBadge_Code) as (
postgres(#              values('01','MB2012')
postgres(#              union all
postgres(#              values('02','JS2012')
postgres(#      ), dCustomers (ID, pPhone_Number) as (
postgres(#              values('01','1800 backhouse')
postgres(#              union all
postgres(#              values('02','1800 both')
postgres(#      ), xPeople (dPeople_ID, dGROUPS_ID) as (
postgres(#              values('001','2')
postgres(#              union all
postgres(#              values('002','3')
postgres(#              union all
postgres(#              values('003','2')
postgres(#              union all
postgres(#              values('003','3')
postgres(#      ), xEmployees (dPeople_ID, dEmployees_ID) as (
postgres(#              values('001','02')
postgres(#              union all
postgres(#              values('003','01')
postgres(#      ), xCustomers (dPeople_ID, dCustomers_ID) as (
postgres(#              values('002','01')
postgres(#              union all
postgres(#              values('003','02')
postgres(#      )
postgres-# select *
postgres-# from (
postgres(#              select ID as dPeople_ID, pFirst_Name, pLast_Name
postgres(#              from dPeople
postgres(#      ) dPeople
postgres-#      left outer join (
postgres(#                      select dPeople_ID, dEmployees_ID, pBadge_Code
postgres(#                      from xEmployees
postgres(#                              join (
postgres(#                                              select ID as dEmployees_ID, pBadge_Code
postgres(#                                              from dEmployees
postgres(#                                      ) as dEmployees using (dEmployees_ID)
postgres(#              ) as Employees using (dPeople_ID)
postgres-#      left outer join (
postgres(#                      select dPeople_ID, dCustomers_ID,  pPhone_Number
postgres(#                      from xCustomers
postgres(#                              join (
postgres(#                                              select ID as dCustomers_ID, pPhone_Number
postgres(#                                              from dCustomers
postgres(#                                      ) as Customers using (dCustomers_ID)
postgres(#              ) as Customers using (dPeople_ID)
postgres-# ;
 dpeople_id | pfirst_name | plast_name | demployees_id | pbadge_code | dcustomers_id | pphone_number
------------+-------------+------------+---------------+-------------+---------------+----------------
 001        | John        | Smith      | 02            | JS2012      |               |
 002        | Anna        | Backhouse  |               |             | 01            | 1800 backhouse
 003        | Mr          | Both       | 01            | MB2012      | 02            | 1800 both
(3 rows)
```